# Remote work in Europe for EU citizen. How does it work from the legal point of view?

Tags: working-visas, eu, paperwork, brazil

I'm a software developer from Latvia (EU country).

I am planning to marry a Brazilian woman and move to Brazil this year for a permanent living. But I will still have EU citizenship. So I would like to find a full-time remote job in one of European countries (Germany / Spain / France / Italy / UK / Any other)

The problem is that I don't know what paperwork should I do to be able to work like this. Do I need any documents to prepare? Do I need any special permissions? Maybe here is someone with a similar experience?

Comment: For sure, you need to have a legal basis to work in Brasil, either an employment or own company.

Answer (score 3):

There are three aspects to your situation:

- Your right to work in Brazil
- Your right to work in the EU / for an EU company
- Taxation of your income

You write you are a software developer. It will possibly make a huge difference if you will be hired as an employee by an EU company while you are living in Brazil (which would legally be possible but according to my experience in the field very unlikely) or if you will be providing a service on a contractual basis to a company in the EU, i.e. you will just agree on a compensation and write them an invoice for your services.

When it comes to working as an employee, it may depend on the country you're hired in, but at least when it comes to Germany they would treat you like any German employee when it comes to taxes.

If you will provide a remote service as a self-employed person, then all your taxation and paperwork will be in Brazil. And you don't even have to be an EU citizen to provide services from Brazil to an EU country.

A way in-between might be to establish / keep a registered company in the EU which you will use to write your invoices. That would most likely make your live easier with certain big accounts in the EU as they are frequently highly sceptical against making contracts with non-EU companies.

Comment: (+1) The last option might be tricky from the point of view of the Brazilian authorities…

Comment: @Gala Not necessarily. As long as he declares his income from the EU based company in Brazil if Brazil will require him to do so. I don't know Brazilian tax laws. The point I was trying to make was that many EU companies will have a hard time contracting with a non-EU resident company and this will solve that problem for him.

Comment: That's a big if. But, yeah, there might be ways to do it above board, hence “might”. The thing is that it's not a full solution, it's displacing the problem. Basically, doing that makes it easier for his clients, which is a good thing from a commercial point of view but that leaves him to figure out all taxes and legal obligations, a burden that would fall on the employer if he was an employee.