# Can you work remotely for a company while being a student in Germany?

Tags: germany, digital-nomads

As a non-EU student in Germany, I'm allowed to work up to ~20 hours per week. Since I cannot freelance or be self-employed, can I somehow work remotely for a foreign company (Malta) while being a student in Germany?
Is this somehow possible, since I would like to continue working for my present company, while being a student in Germany. I'm guessing a brand new contract will have to be made with specific working hours etc.
Is this at all possible somehow? And if so, how?

Comment: First, you may apply for a permission for freelance, but it might be hard to get it, see https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/14430/13223. Second, you may even change your residence permit type, but not so easily: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/19837/13223 (please also see comments there, you may need a permission from current employer to have extra job). The most unclear point, as I see, is working for company in other country (Malta), it was already asked https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/20317/13223 https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/5621/13223

Comment: Finally, if you are not freelancer, your maltesian company might need to pay taxes and make social payments for you in Germany, which might be rather complicated, so that you/they will need to consult a lawyer or tax cunsultant: https://www.recht-spanien.com/index.php/de/blog-de/unternehmen/373-steuern-telearbeit.html